# How to bulge out the curved edges of the stereographic tesseract?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polytopes

You probably already saw such a representation of the tesseract:

[image: Tesseract]

I did something similar on [my blog](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/StereoTruncatedTesseract.html) for the truncated tesseract:

[image: Truncated tesseract]

The vertices in 3D are the stereographic projections of the original 4D vertices. This point is clear. However I don't know how the varying radius of the bent tubular edges should be chosen. To get a bent 3D edge, I project the corresponding 4D edge on the 3-sphere and then I stereographically project the bent 4D edge. But how to choose the radii? The way I use on my blog consists in arbitrarily taking a radius "proportional" to the norm of the 3D point (e.g. I take $\log\bigl((1 + \lVert M \rVert)/4\bigr)/4$, because I empirically found this choice yields a pretty result). Is there a mathematical consideration that would justify to have a radius "proportional" to the norm of 3D point? What is the meaning of the value of the radius?

Schleimer and Segerman, the authors of the paper [Sculptures in $S^3$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.4952) (see Figure 3) have a different approach and I don't understand it:

> A better solution is to use tubular neighbourhoods in the intermediate $S^3$ geometry. For this we must parameterise the image of such a tube under stereographic projection. Here the circline property is very useful. The boundary of a tubular neighbourhood of a geodesic in $S^3$ can be made as a union of small circles in $\mathbb R^4$. (These circles lie in $S^3$, but are not great.) The small circles map to circlines in $\mathbb R^3$, which can be
> directly parameterised. Computer visualisation of stereographic projections of 4-polytopes, in this style, are beautifully rendered by the program Jenn3d [8]. In Figure 3 we show four views of a 3D print of the 24–cell, ….

Comment: When possible, it is better to enter text directly, rather than as a non-searchable image.  If you don't feel like typing it, then, for a "modern" TeXed paper, you can often copy and paste directly from the PDF for a result that requires only a little tidying.  I edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, @LSpice! I agree with your remark, sorry.

Comment: I included the animation from my blog, and it does not appear anymore, why?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455514/how-to-bulge-out-the-curved-edges-of-the-stereographic-tesseract#comment1179358_455514), my apologies.  I always forget that MathOverflow (or is it HTML in general?) is very finicky about where the `alt=""` attribute goes in an `img`.  I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

One natural choice (if not necessarily the best choice) is to pick a small $\epsilon$, take the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood in the three-sphere, and stereographically project that to euclidean space.  To actually do this requires a bit of spherical trig.  Note also that there is no "need" to work in $S^3$.  You can instead work with the spherical metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Yes, this is my understanding of the cited paper, but how to parameterize an $\epsilon$-tube?

Comment: You know how to parameterize a tube in euclidean space with varying tube-radius - so use the ratio between the euclidean metric and the spherical metric to determine the desired tube-radius.  Details: let $ds_\mathbb{E}$ be the euclidean line element.  Then $ds_\mathbb{S} = 2 ds_\mathbb{E} / (1 + r^2)$ is the spherical line element.  (Here $r$ is the euclidean distance to the origin.) So at a point euclidean distance $r$ from the origin, you want the tube-radius to be $\epsilon (1 + r^2)/2$.